# How child record overrides parent record columns?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server I have a table:

```
ShopID  Name    Description MetaDescription ParentShopID
5       NULL    NULL        NULL            4
4       NULL    D4          NULL            3
3       NULL    NULL        MD3             2
2       N2      NULL        NULL            1
1       N1      D1          MD1             NULL
```

there is a hierarchy concept which every `ShopID` has its `ParentShopID`.

I want to get the the `ShopID=5` record, But in a way that the `NULL` valued columns in itT should be replaced with its parents recursively.

The result should be like this:

```
ShopID  Name    Description MetaDescription ParentShopID
5       N2      D4          MD3             4
```

The performance and cost is very important to me. so I'm not inclined to use `Cursor` for that.

Is there any good solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with basic recursive CTE:

```
; with CTE as (
    select * from Table1 where ParentShopID is NULL
    union all
    select 
      T.ShopId, 
      isnull(T.Name,C.Name),
      isnull(T.Description, C.Description),
      isnull(T.MetaDescription, C.MetaDescription), 
      T.ParentShopId
    from CTE C 
    join Table1 T on T.ParentShopID = C.ShopID
)
```

Result:

```
ShopID  Name    Descr   MetaDescr   ParentShopID
1       N1      D1      MD1        
2       N2      D1      MD1         1
3       N2      D1      MD3         2
4       N2      D4      MD3         3
5       N2      D4      MD3         4
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba1d9/1)